# Interview process: After sending work samples that I've asked from the company

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I am a graphic designer, currently looking for new opportunities.

I had an interview with HR last week, and they asked me to create some work examples for them.

I spent my time and efforts to make it, After submitting my samples, I haven't heard from them. (A week has passed already)

It's not my first time. I am so upset about getting ignored after sending the work examples.

Does it only happen to me? I've been in this industry for 6 y ears, but I still can't deal with this situation rationally.

I know that a lot of companies never get back to candidates after interview,
But if they get work samples from candidates, I think the company should say something (Not just ignoring them).

I was writing the follow up email, but stopped it.
Should I send the email again?

Comment: Have patience. One week may be less time for HR. They may need some more time. And even if they don't get back to you, don't be upset. Nothing is waste. You should have gained some good experience by doing the sample work.

Comment: If they asked you to create some specific samples for them, I'd watch out for their products in the near future and see if your work samples are used in their products, and then you see a lawyer.

Comment: "But if they get work samples from candidates, I think the company should say something (Not just ignoring them)." This is the world according to whom?

Comment: how long did it take you do do that "work samples"? fake interviews to get work done for free are sadly a common scam

Answer (score 3):

You might want to **wait for the next week** to send a follow-up email.

You have only waited one week so far, and it's *the week right before Christmas.* There's a very high chance that, in this specific case, the process gets slowed down considerably because the people qualified for reviewing are on holiday.

Prepare your email, but hold on sending until January 2nd, to make sure that people will not miss it due to holidays.

In the general case, it is common that companies do not send any feedback if they do not intend to go further in the recruitment process with you. It does not happen only to you, and it will happen to you more in the future. Just let it go, you  can't change that.